# Convert Python string to its ASCII representants

Tags: python

How do I convert a string in Python to its ASCII hex representants?

**Example:** I want to result `'\x00\x1b\xd4}\xa4\xf3\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'` in `001bd47da4f3`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> text = '\x00\x1b\xd4}\xa4\xf3\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'.rstrip('\0')
>>> print "".join("%02x" % ord(c) for c in text)
001bd47da4f3
```

As per martineau's comment, here is the Python 3 way:

```
>>> "".join(format(ord(c),"02x") for c in text)
```

Comment: +1 because it's the best answer and it's not Python version dependent.

Comment: I chose this solution because I think it's the most intuitive; but @martineau: it IS Python version dependent. As far as I know is the `%` parameter not supported anymore in Python 3.

Comment: @Manuel Faux: Oops, my mistake. Well, since it *could* changed to: `print "".join(format(ord(c),"02x") for c in text)` which would at least make it work from 2.6 to 3.x, I won't take the +1 back since it was close. ;-)

Comment: @Manuel Faux, @Ryan Ginstrom: See my own Python version independent answer below which doesn't rely on string formatting or interpolation.

Comment: @Ryan Ginstrom: Actually the `"".join(format(ord(c),"02x") for c in text)` version should work in Python 2.6, 2.7, *and* Python 3.

Answer (score 5):

With python 2.x you can encode a string to it's hex representation. It will not work with python3.x

```
>>> print '\x00\x1b\xd4}\xa4\xf3\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'.encode("hex")
'001bd47da4f300000000000000000000'
```

It's not entirely clear if you have a literal string containing the escapes (so basically r'\x00\x1b' and so on) or not. Also, it's unclear why you don't expect the trailing zeroes, but you can remove those before the encode using .rstrip("\x00")

Comment: Good point about the possible embedded escapes. Also strange that everyone is using the sample input, but no one has commented about the fact that it's messed-up (missing '7d' and has '}' in it) -- yet all give desired output...

Comment: } doesn't need an escape, but escaped it would have been \x7d. The string makes perfect sense, just not all characters are escaped.

Comment: It's entirely clear from the OP's input and output that the input is '\x00\x1b' etc not r'\x00\x1b' etc.

Comment: Wow, can't believe I didn't notice that '}' is \x7d -- guess @Glenn Maynard is right.

Answer (score 4):

Alternative:

```
[Python 2.7]
>>> data = '\x00\x1b\xd4}\xa4\xf3\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.b2a_hex(data.rstrip('\x00'))
'001bd47da4f3'
>>>

[Python 3.1.2]
>>> data = b'\x00\x1b\xd4}\xa4\xf3\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.b2a_hex(data.rstrip(b'\x00'))
b'001bd47da4f3'
>>>
```

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: "hexlify" is silly, it's not even a portmanteau word (that would be "hexify") whereas a few seconds perusal of the binascii docs reveals that the non-silly names follow a pattern ... b2a_hex means "binary to ascii, hex mode"

Comment: FWIW, whether or not `hexlify()` a "proper" portmanteau or just seems silly to you, it **is** one of the two names for same function in the `binascii` module -- so consider that obviously others must have also thought it's a more descriptive or readable name, too.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another answer that ought to work with all Python versions from 3.x all the way back to 2.0 (min version according to [pyqver](http://github.com/ghewgill/pyqver)). Despite that, because it's based on a simple table (not dict) lookup, it should also be relatively quick.

A little one-time set-up is required, but is very simple and avoids using the any of the many enhancements that have were added (or removed) along the way in a quest for version independence.

```
numerals = "0123456789abcdef"
hexadecimal = [i+j for i in numerals for j in numerals]

text = '\x00\x1b\xd4}\xa4\xf3\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'    
print ''.join([hexadecimal[ord(c)] for c in text.rstrip('\0')])
# 001bd47da4f3
```

Answer (score -4):

[`binascii.hexlify()`](http://docs.python.org/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify):

```
import binascii

byte_string = '\x00\x1b\xd4}\xa4\xf3\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' 
print binascii.hexlify(byte_string.rstrip('\x00'))

# -> 001bd47da4f3
```

See [@John Machin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850531/convert-python-string-to-its-ascii-representants/3851622#3851622).

Comment: Stripping the output is correct, I think. He wants to remove tailing zeros in the result.

Comment: -1 Bizarre Baroque Byzantine Bassackwards Solution of the Month

Comment: @IvovanderWijk:  I've updated the answer. Would you mind deleting your outdated comment? binascii.hexlify() stood the test of time (it works on both Python 2/3 ("abc".encode('hex') works only in Python 2 and b"abc".hex() works only in Python 3.5+).